# How to refer the generic type of super class in subclass in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types, reference

I have following base class

```
class Base<T> {
    // ...
}
```

and I have this class to extend the Base

```
class Derived extends Base<String> {
    public void doSomething(String param) { // this works

    }

    public void doSomething(Base::T param) { // this DOES NOT work

    }
}
```

I want know whether there is a java trick to get the second function definition to work without using the concrete class `String` directly?

Comment: `String` is a final class in Java, so nothing can extend it.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the method parameter to be generic, or just curious?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim. I am not going to exterd `String`. What I want to is refer a generic type from super class.

Comment: You did.  It's String.

Comment: since you don't want to bound base type, may be just generic method would suffice `public <T> void doSomething(T t){}`

Comment: A subclass can only have its own type variables, but its superclass might use them.  For example, if you had `Derived<T> extends Base<T>`, then you could refer to `T`.  As it is, the type argument to `Base` is fixed: it's `String`, so Java expects you to refer to it as `String`.

Comment: @Jaybird Yes I have a reason. There are many classes need extend the Base<T> with different concrete type. I want to avoid change the funciton signature in each class, this should be avoided if possible.

Comment: That makes sense. If it turns out that it's not possible, at least the code is more readable as you can see directly what the parameter type is.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, this is the only work around I can image so far although it requires extra indirect layer. If there is well accepted way to refer to a generic type at compiler time, I will have to resort to this finally. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

> Yes I have a reason. There are many classes need extend the Base with different concrete type. I want to avoid change the funciton signature in each class, this should be avoided if possible.

If you have many classes that need to extend the `Base<T>` class and they all have a `doSomething` method, you should probably put the `doSomething` in `Base<T>`:

```
class Base<T> {
    public void doSomething(T param) {} // or even make this abstract
}
```

And then, IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA can generate the overridden method for you. When you start typing the method name, this pops up:

[image]

You press enter, and then it will be generated for you.

```
@Override
public void doSomething(String param) {
    super.doSomething(param);
}
```

---

I suspect that you might be copy and pasting the implementation of `doSomething`, because otherwise why you think it is annoying to change the parameter type for each implementation?

If the implementations are mostly the same, consider having the `doSomething` method in the `Base<T>`, then extract the parts that are different into a `doSomethingImpl` method which will be overridden by the derived classes.

Comment: I'd be concerned if the implementations were mostly the same because the only class a non-bounded wildcard can refer to in the base class is `Object`.

Comment: @Powerlord for e.g. T extends Number method body can be exactly the same characters and yet they refer to different methods and operators. I am not sure what the OP is up to, but same text might still yield different valid functions.

Comment: You are right. The `doSomething` is defined in super class and should be overridden in subclass. `Derived` class is only a wrapper to call `super.doSomething(param)` on need. As there are many similar wrappers and each has some functions invloves the concrete type, use the T instead of concrete class is very attactive. I have a little C++ backgroud and type reference is much easier there and wonder whetehr I can find similar support from Java. So far it seems no direct solution for this.

Comment: @Bingfeng If it just calls `super.doSomething(param)`, you don't need to override it. Just declare `doSomething` in the base class and it will be inherited in the derived classes.

Comment: @TheConstructor If you think `String` (used in the OP's example) matches `T extends Number`, you might want to rethink things. ;)

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunaly there maybe other codes before/after call `super.doSomething(param)`. I have move all common codes to `Base<T>` already.

Comment: You are not copy-pasting the implementation right? Then why is having to write different parameter types bothering you? @Bingfeng

Comment: Hmm, as I have specified the concrete type in `Base<String>` (maybe other type, `String` is used here for example), restate it in any related method seems duplicated. I want to eliminate this duplication, this is my intent. In fact there are four generic types (related but not the same) defined in `Base` and I would like refer to them in need. Trying to repeat them all? Hope not do that. @Sweeper

Comment: @Bingfeng Well, this cannot be done in Java, or any other language that I know. I really don't think this is a problem in the first place...

Comment: @Powerlord I am not the SAP-database-driver (which seems to ignore numeric db-types completely). I was just remembering that I once wanted some "add two Number"-function and basically had to either convert all or replicate the text for each concrete sub-class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass different parameters to your method, you can implement an upper bounded type parameter.

```
class Derived<T extends Foo> extends Base<Foo> {
   public void doSomething(Foo param) { // this works

   }
}

public <T extends Foo> void doSomething(List<T> foos) {}
public void doSomething(List<Foo> foo) {}
```

Given: `class Bar extends Foo { }`

```
List<Bar> list = new ArrayList<Bar>();
doSomething(list);
```

Comment: While this is good in a general sense, if `String` is one of the child types, you're limited as to which bounded type that can be.  Specifically `String` is only an `Object`, `Serializable`, and `CharSequence`; `String` is also a final class and thus has no child classes.

Comment: Yes. That's right. Making String as an upper-bound directly won't help with the same.